# The Name '' Does not Exists in the Current Context

Tags: c#, wpf

I get a compilation error:

> The Name '' Does not Exists in the Current Context

The problem is `blacklist` and `blocked`.

How can I resolve this issue?

See my code below:

```
CommService.CommServiceClient client = new CommService.CommServiceClient();
            
string cardId = txtCardId.Text;
string cardType = cboCardType.Text;
string cardPin = txtCardPin.Text;

    if (radEnab.IsChecked == true)
    {
        string blacklist = Convert.ToString(radEnab.DataContext);
    }

    if (radDis.IsChecked == true)
    {
        string blacklist = Convert.ToString(radDis.DataContext);
    }
    
    if (radEnab2.IsChecked == true)
    {
        string blocked = Convert.ToString(radEnab2.DataContext);
    }

    if (radDis2.IsChecked == true)
    {
         string blocked = Convert.ToString(radDis2.DataContext);
    }
         
    string startDate = StartDate.Text;
    string expiryDate = ExpiryDate.Text;
    string zone = cboZone.Text;
           
    string data = cardId + cardType + cardPin + blacklist + blocked + startDate + expiryDate + zone;
    client.ReceiveDataFromApp("R1", "11", "161.100.100.79", "4000", data);
```

Comment: You know that you are declaring the `blacklist` and `blocklist` as there scope local to the only if condition right ? And if you want to use them else where declare in relative scope.

Comment: Declare those variables outside of the if's curly braces. Currently variable scope is only within if block and you are trying to use them outside scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare `blacklist` and `blocked` in the scope where `data` variable can access. In your case, you are declaring `blacklist` and blocked inside `if` scope which `data` variable can not access.

You should do like this  to get access to blacklist and blocked:

```
        string blacklist = string.Empty;
        string blocked = string.Empty;
        if (radEnab.IsChecked == true)
        {
            blacklist = Convert.ToString(radEnab.DataContext);
        }

        if (radDis.IsChecked == true)
        {
            blacklist = Convert.ToString(radDis.DataContext);
        }
        if (radEnab2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            blocked = Convert.ToString(radEnab2.DataContext);
        }

        if (radDis2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            blocked = Convert.ToString(radDis2.DataContext);
        }

        string startDate = StartDate.Text;
        string expiryDate = ExpiryDate.Text;
        string zone = cboZone.Text;

      string data = cardId + cardType + cardPin + blacklist + blocked + startDate + expiryDate + zone;
      client.ReceiveDataFromApp("R1", "11", "161.100.100.79", "4000", data);
```

For better understanding of local variable scope, have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samng/archive/2007/11/09/local-variable-scoping-in-c.aspx)

Comment: Glad, it help you. You can accept the answer if it is right for you :)